# I want to know how to quickly reset(clear) eMMc(SD). (dd is too slow!)

Tags: filesystems, memory, hardware

I am using an embedded board.
I am using `eMMc(8GB)` as a boot device.(I also use SD cards.)
I think I need to reset the boot device if I reinstall the OS.
So I tried reset with the following command.
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1`
/dev/mmcblk1 is eMMc.
However, resetting 8GB to /dev/zero with the dd command takes too long!
But I think this is the most obvious way.
Is there a way to reset (clear) the boot device memory faster?

Comment: Just reformat it? `mkfs.ext4` or whatever you use.

Comment: @jiggunjer I want a low-format (hex valueres)

Comment: Is it technically possible? Then there might be a tool. I'd like to know this too, +1. But you might consider electrical engineering stackexchange also.

Comment: @jiggunjer Formatting with mkfs.ext4 will result in formatting. However, if you look at the value of `hex` in the low level with the dd command, existing data remains. If you copy to /dev/zero, all hex values are initialized to 0x00. However, copying dd to /dev/zero takes too long. I am concerned with the low hex values that remain when formatting with mkfs.ext4.

Comment: Try larger block size like 1M?

Comment: @jiggunjer I tested it according to your suggestion. I tested it with a 16GB SD card. When bs=512, 185 minutes and 25 seconds were required. bs=1M required 104 minutes and 6 seconds.

Comment: It shouldn't be that slow. I've zeroed entire partitions on my laptop with that in minutes.

Comment: @jiggunjer In my first test I tested it with /dev/urandom. I tested it again with /dev/zero. bs=512 took 70 minutes and 35 seconds, and bs=1M took 24 minutes and 10 seconds.My SD card is 16GB and class6.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use:

```
blkdiscard /dev/mmcblk1
```